# Custom progressbar for android

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-progressbar

Is it possible to make progress bar like following image.

[image]

Star have to be filled up by giving percentage. Any help will be highly appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: if you could have gif file of above wshich will fill the star and showing custom gif file in android may help

Comment: There is a lib for that. But its for Jelly Bean and above.

Comment: you can write custom view, and by using handler in side that you can apply animation also.

Comment: @Tushar That is enough bro, Can you tell me lib name and location.

Comment: @NoName, You are right, I can draw star, But how can I fill it.

Comment: do you have animation effect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

There is a library to get this above animation.

Find it [here](https://github.com/RomainPiel/Titanic).

It's not complicated to use. all you have to do is add the following custom view in layout

```
<com.romainpiel.titanic.TitanicTextView
    android:id="@+id/titanic_tv"
    android:text="@string/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#212121"
    android:textSize="70sp"/>
```

and then start it like:

```
titanic = new Titanic();
titanic.start(myTitanicTextView);
```

Yes, you can use it instead of progressBar. All you  have to do is override it's code according to your requirements.

Comment: Super bro, Wait, I will accept it as answer after meet my requirement. Added +1.

Comment: You'll have to override its code and put limits on the animation accordingly. But this is by far the closest thing that is present to your requirement. Glad to help :)

Comment: No bro .. I have worked on it for one hour only. I can't get it. When I have free time I will rework on it. Thank you.

Comment: how can i use that code to fill circleFillView with this type of animation to change the progress values